# Using an Element as the key to a Hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hashmap, weakmap

I want to create a hash with DOM elements as keys. This is illustrated by the following code:

```
var hash = {};
var set = function(element, value) {  hash[element] = value; };
var get = function(element)        {  return hash[element];  };

set(document.getElementById('foo'), 'bar');
get(document.getElementById('foo')); // returns 'bar'
```

How can I ensure that hash maps to a unique value for each `Element`?
Note that I can't use the raw ID string as key, because any arbitrary `Element` may be passed in, including those without a id.

Comment: why would you `document.getElementById` when you can directly use the `id`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Sorry this was a simplified example, I do need to key off the element.

Comment: You may want to check [this thread on unique arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what do you mean?

Comment: @GriffLab Many DOM nodes do not have an "id" attribute, so these cannot be uniquely identified by their id string. The OP wants to get the ability to use any DOM node as key.

Comment: @RobW Oh ok cool, I got confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript until ES 6, only strings can be used as a key. If you want to use DOM elements, either use two linked lists, or the [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) object. A bonus of the latter method is that it does not cause memory leaks.

Applied to your example:

```
var hash = new WeakMap();
hash.set(document.getElementById('foo'), 'bar');
hash.get(document.getElementById('foo')); // returns 'bar'
```

As of writing, `WeakMap` is only supported by the following browsers:

- Firefox 6
- Chrome 19 (disabled by default, see [instructions to enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253177/938089))
- Opera 15 (disabled by default, start Opera with `--js-flags=--harmony` to enable it).
- Internet Explorer 11 ([confirmed to exist in leaked build](http://fremycompany.com/BG/2013/Internet-Explorer-11-rsquo-s-leaked-build-395/))

In all other browsers, WeakMap support can be achieved by loading the [WeakMap.js](https://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/src/ses/WeakMap.js) polyfill.

Comment: _"Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes."_

Comment: @gdoron A polyfill is available, such as [Weakmap.js](https://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/src/ses/WeakMap.js), in case you worry about browser compatibility.

Comment: "A bonus of the latter method is that it does not cause memory leaks." I'd argue in this case OP should just use a regular map.

Comment: This answer is not correct in current chrome; HTMLDivElement instances will act as the same key as their `.toString()` representation.